# My external hdd not mounting on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: mount, windows, ntfs, external-hdd, cache

Heres the error message i get every time i try to mount it via terminal

The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sde2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option

Answer (score 0):

This happens on internal drives too. The way to fix this on internal would be to completely shutdown Windows holding the shift button while clicking shutdown. Please make sure you ejected the drive before you shutdown Windows. Another solution, would be to unmount and reformat the drive to ext4 using gparted. This would erase all data on the drive (if any) and would be very difficult for Windows to read without other software. If you don't have Windows or data on the drive, feel free to do the reformat. I hope this helped!

Comment: I cannot  format it because I need the files thats on the drive I am using it as an external